# is there any concept in statistic that make a variable unit free?

Tags: statistics

I am very amatory in statistic . my question is that is there any concept in statistic that remove unit of a variable?
For example suppose I have age and wight, finding the mean of theses two is meaningless for me because they have different units. How I can make them unit free?

Comment: Standardization (where you replace $X$ with $Z= (X-\mu)/\sigma$) does this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you can consider is standardizing the random variable.

$$Z =\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}$$

where $\mu$ is the mean of the random variable $X$ and $\sigma$ is the standard deviation of $X$.

Comment: what do you mean by random variable? my variable are not random

Comment: It means that you standardize the data. Subtract the mean and then divide by the standard deviation. You then know how many standard deviations from the mean each observation is.